# Lambda function to start or stop ec2 based on application usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, aws-lambda, amazon-route53

I would like to investigate that whether it is possible or not that if someone tries to hit the application url then instance should be re-enabled and remain active as long as there is active use. If the resources are inactive for 10 to 20 mins they should automatically disable themselves i.e. instance should get disabled.
Here there are Multi host Application deployed on ec2 instance and configured record set dns in Route53. 
Pls suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a `ec2 start` lambda function that gets called when you hit the `url` hosted on APIGateway backed by this lambda, once the instance is up redirect to the actual ec2 instance `url`(So the lambda will have to keep checking the status of the ec2 instance once running redirect to this url).
- On starting the `ec2 instance` trigger another lambda on the event pattern on the `state` as `running` basis which will attach a cloudwatch alarm to the instance.
- The cloudwatch alarm will check on the cpu usage and if it goes below 10% for 3 consecutive times it will stop the instance.
- The lambda should have the role with policy having full access to the EC2 instance(later on change it to the required method privileges).
  [blog on stop/start ec2 instance](https://medium.com/@Hironsan/save-aws-ec2-cost-by-automatically-stopping-idle-instance-using-lambda-and-cloudwatch-759edd62b27d)
  [aws knowledge centre](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/)
  [aws Instance Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/instance-scheduler/welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an **AWS Alarm** to monitor usage or activity.
2. Use an **SNS topic** to trigger a **Lambda** function based on the Alarm
3. Turn off the ec2 instance based using Python in Lambda

This should help with the code:
https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-automatically-turning-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-d7f414390800